# Dealing with MySQL database quotas

Tags: database

I have my Drupal site hosted at a society that gave me a 400M database quota.  After 4 weeks of production, it has reached 100M.  I predict that after a year, it will reach the limit.

Is any way to reduce the database size, so I don't have problems with my quota?

Comment: Do you have cron running?  This will clean up old data from the cache and logs.

Comment: yes of course, i used [http://drupal.org/project/cron_cache] module to empty the cache

Comment: Which tables are the big ones?

Comment: If you have a lot of nodes/fields the search_index table can get pretty large - if so you could always get yourself a SOLR instance (preferably on the same class C net at least) and that will alleviate some of the strain

Comment: -1 on not mentioning _anything_ about the content/setup of the site. How can the question be answered when the problem is complete guesswork? If editors are churning out new content on a daily basis, you can't "just shrink the database."

Comment: I don't use drupal search but the google search only

Comment: What do you want to know more? i have arround 500 ndoes

Comment: This is really not a drupal question but db related.

Comment: @Mike It is a Drupal related question. The problem is that it doesn't give enough information, and the answers would be similar to "If you are using this module, then you should do this." If who answers needs to guess the installed modules, how many users have an account on that site, and other details, then it is not anymore answering, but guessing.

Comment: @mohammedaminebourkadi What you need to say is which Drupal version you are using, which modules are used, how many users are active in the website, etc. Without much information, it is not possible to answer. If every answer starts with "if you are using this module," then it is not anymore answering, but guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just shrink the database by optimizing every MyISAM you have

You can use to monitor how much space you database is taking up (in MB):

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(dbtb,'Total') tablename,
    (datsize+ndxsize)/power(1024,pw) table_size
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name) dbtb,
    data_length datsize,index_length ndxsize
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema NOT IN
    ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')
) A,(SELECT 2 pw) B
GROUP BY dbtb WITH ROLLUP;
```

This will add up all used data and index space.

I have other queries for measuring the amount of used space for MyISAM and InnoDB

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1307/877
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5708/877
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18952/877

If there is significant difference between in these queries' output and what your OS says you are using, try shrinking each individual table as follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT('OPTIMIZE TABLE ',dbtb,';') OptimizeCommand
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name) dbtb
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema NOT IN
    ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')
) A;
```

Export the output of this query to a SQL text file and run it:

```
SQLFILE=/tmp/OptimizeSQLScript.sql
SQLCMD="SELECT CONCAT('OPTIMIZE TABLE ',dbtb,';') FROM ("
SQLCMD="${SQLCMD} SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name) dbtb "
SQLCMD="${SQLCMD} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN "
SQLCMD="${SQLCMD} ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')) A"
mysql -u... -p... -ANe"${SQLCMD}" > ${SQLFILE}
mysql -u... -p... < ${SQLFILE}
```

An even faster way without fancy parsing would be to mysqldump the entire dataset and reload it

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --all-databases --routines --triggers > mydata.sql
mysql -u... -p... < mydata.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!